# GCP Cloud build with cloud function doesn't deploy the latest code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I am trying to setup CI/CD pipeline with Google Cloud Build for deploying the Google Cloud Functions with GitHub repository.

I have managed to create the trigger and whenever i push changes to master branch, the build is triggering. But after the deployment and Cloud Function Version is incremented, when i invoke the cloud function, it still executing the old function.

Following is the buildconfig.yaml

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
  args: ['clone', 'https://github.com/mayuran19/GCP-CloudFunction']
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
  args: ['pull', 'https://github.com/mayuran19/GCP-CloudFunction', 'master']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'function-1', '--trigger-http', '--runtime', 'nodejs8', '--entry-point', 'helloWorld']
  dir: './'
```

Comment: Did you retry now? functions take sometine time to rollout all the instances.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, Yes i did, i don't think that is the problem because the deployment version is increased. That means i hope the deployment is done and ready to use. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's challenging to debug Cloud Build but I think you're missing the correct deployment source.

The `git clone ...` step creates `/workspace/GCP-CloudFunction`

But you `gcloud functions deploy ...` from (default == `/workspace`).

You need to point `gcloud functions deploy ... --source=./GCP-CloudFunction`. (since you're in `/workspace`; or `--source=/workspace/GCP-CloudFunction` to be explicit).

A useful debugging mechanism is to add e.g. a `busybox` step that `ls -la /workspace` to ensure that, the workspace contains what you're expecting.

Comment: @DazWikin, Thanks much, it worked, couldn't find much resources on how to do this in quick search.

Comment: Super! I agree that there documentation could be improved.